# Real time recording and playing audio as buffer

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

the title is indicating what I want, I just want to record audio as buffer and play that byte with only javascript at the same time (not node js) .
I researched about that for a while, and finally, I tried this method, and works for recording

```
        const handleSuccess = function(stream) {
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024*4, 1, 1);

        source.connect(processor);
        processor.connect(context.destination);

        processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
            
            console.log(e);
        };
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then(handleSuccess);
```

now the problem is playing this `e`
I tried decoding it with `context.decodeAudioData(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).buffer)` but it throws an error :

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data`

why it's not working? `e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).buffer` returns an object of type `ArrayBuffer` which is exactly what `decodeAudioData` wants, I also ensured that the output array is not empty.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `audioprocess` event of a `ScriptProcessorNode` gives you access to the current audio as an `AudioBuffer`. If you want to play that `AudioBuffer` you can use it as is and don't need to decode it anymore. It's already decoded. It can be played with an `AudioBufferSourceNode`.

The `ScriptProcessorNode` is officially deprecated but I guess it will never go away. Its successor - the `AudioWorkletProcessor` - gives you access to the raw channel data.